# TargetEntity property for JpaRepository

Tags: java, generics, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm experimenting with the spring-data-jpa project and implemented some arbitrary API and put the JPA entity definitions in the implementing classes. The (one) Repository is defined as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<RecipeEntity, Long>
```

My entity class is defined as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipes")
public class RecipeEntity implements Recipe
```

So I´m building a recipe like this:

```
Recipe pasta = Kitchen.createRecipe("Pasta");
```

And for sure I cannot simply persist the recipe like this:

```
recipeRepository.save(pasta);
```

So it would be nice if I could just define the repository like this:

```
@Repository(targetEntity=RecipeEntity.class)
public interface RecipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Recipe, Long>
```

Just as I reference associated entities from the RecipeEntity for example the ingredients:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=IngredientEntity.class)
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
```

Comment: It really does not make any sense to persist an interface. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Yeah, that´s what they say - I´m building a recipe with my API and want to save it afterwards. The entity classes also have references to other interfaces and you can use targetEntity to point to the persisting class. So actually I´m looking for something like targetEntity for the save method.

Comment: If I understand your intentions correctly, you can achieve the desired behavior by switching from interfaces to abstract classes.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. But I think the code above is not very far from the solution using interfaces. RecipeImpl implements Recipe, Recipe extends Persistable, Persistable defines the getPersistableEntity() method that is finally implemented by RecipeImpl which returns RecipeImpl.class. When I inspect pasta.getPersistableEntity().cast(pasta) in the debugger it actually returns an object of RecipeImpl but the save() method of the Repository cannot handle it.

Comment: follow the simple path... I'm lost in your logic. Why do you try to complicate things?

Comment: I´m sorry ;-) I just try to learn and figure out some things - this is not going to be any productive code.

Comment: Oh, and the learning path is not supposed to be simple ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but you should learn only reasonable things $)

Comment: There was an answer which had been deleted - I just read "make Persistable generic" which kind of does the trick but leaks the implementations into the interfaces. Anyway when I declare Recipe like this: interface Recipe extends Persistable<RecipeImpl> the save works.